# Flutter sqfline error while initializing the base table

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am trying to add SQFlite to my flutter project. But while initializing the database, I am getting the following error.

```
E/SQLiteLog(26082): (1) near "references": syntax error
I/flutter (26082): error DatabaseException(near "references": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE cv (
I/flutter (26082):             id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
I/flutter (26082):             name TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             image TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             signature TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             skills TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             address TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             country TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             education TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             email TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             phone TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             objective TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             references TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):             experience TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (26082):           )) during open, closing...
E/flutter (26082): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "references": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE cv (
E/flutter (26082):             id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
E/flutter (26082):             name TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             image TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             signature TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             skills TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             address TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             country TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             education TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             email TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             phone TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             objective TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             references TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):             experience TEXT NOT NULL,
E/flutter (26082):           ))
E/flutter (26082): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:29:7)
E/flutter (26082): #2      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:183:15)
E/flutter (26082): #3      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.invokeExecute (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:328:12)
E/flutter (26082): #4      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnExecute.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:323:14)
E/flutter (26082): #5      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:275:26)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #6      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnWriteSynchronized (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:307:7)
E/flutter (26082): #7      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnExecute (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:313:12)
E/flutter (26082): #8      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin&SqfliteDatabaseExecutorMixin.execute (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:35:15)
E/flutter (26082): #9      DatabaseHelper._onCreate (package:cv_builder/db_helper.dart:35:14)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #10     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:661:29)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #11     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin._runTransaction (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:433:28)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #12     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.transaction.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:450:14)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #13     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:275:26)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #14     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnWriteSynchronized (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:307:7)
E/flutter (26082): #15     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.transaction (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:449:12)
E/flutter (26082): #16     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:651:15)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #17     SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase (package:sqflite/src/database.dart:32:22)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #18     _SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl&Object&SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite/src/factory_mixin.dart:100:43)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #19     ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:33:24)
E/flutter (26082): #20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter (26082): #21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter (26082): #22     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
E/flutter (26082): #23     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
E/flutter (26082): #24     ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:32:24)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #25     BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:31:26)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #26     ReentrantLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:28:17)
E/flutter (26082): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26082): #27     _SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl&Object&SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase (package:sqflite/src/factory_mixin.dart:66:17)
E/flutter (26082): #28     openDatabase (package:sqflite/sqflite.dart:150:26)
E/flutter (26082): #29     DatabaseHelper._initDatabase (
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the last line of sql query `experience TEXT NOT NULL,`
Update it to `experience TEXT NOT NULL`
remove the comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

of course,this solution would have solved your problem , But in my scenario this was not the case . My Syntax was right . My query was big so the compiler was causing error. This was just solved separating query into a string variable and then passing to database query function.

e.g,

**This would cause an error.**

```dart
await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE TEST(.................
..................)
''');
```

**Solution :**

```dart
String query='''
CREATE TABLE TEST(.................
..................)
''';

await db.execute(query);
```